# Hatching area between two symbolic curves matlab

Tags: matlab, area, curves

I need to shade the area between symbolic curves and the x axis.

```
syms x

j(1) = x^2
j(2) = x^3
j(3) = x^5
j(4) = x^6

for i = 1:4
    subplot(2,2,i);
    f(i) = ezplot(j(i),[0,6000]);
    Hatch(f(i))
end
```

This gives me an error. After looking in the matlab documentation, i end up with codes like

```
f1 := plot::Function2d(sqrt(x), x = 0..2, Color = RGB::Black):
```

Is this even matlab code? What's with the "::" and ":="? Why does this throw an error?
Thanks for any help guys!

Thanks!

Comment: This is maple code. Have a look to MuPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you command under `mupad` and after to call it with Matlab command window have a look to this : [MatLab and MuPad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html)

For more information go [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html)

Answer (score 2):

The line `f1 := plot::Function2d(sqrt(x), x = 0..2, Color = RGB::Black):` is for MuPad (Symbolic Math toolbox). However, you can evaluate the symbolic functions without this toolbox using Matlab's `ezplot`.

The following figure

[image]

is given by (please see the comments that made your code work)

```
f{1} = 'x^2'; % declare as cell array {} of string ''
f{2} = 'x^3';
f{3} = 'x^5';
f{4} = 'x^6';

figure('Color', 'w');
for ii = 1:4                          %do not use i or j in Matlab
    subplot(2,2,ii);
    h(ii) = ezplot(f{ii},[0,6000]);   %the correct way to call ezplot
    x = get(h(ii), 'XData');          %get the x and y data
    y = get(h(ii), 'YData');
    area(x,y,'FaceColor',[.7 0 0]);   %plot the (x,y) area in red
end
```

Comment: Nice to know about the cell array of string. Thanks